# Different error messages when using different strings in terminal

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, error-handling, stderr

When I insert, for example, `unix.stackexchange.com` followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> in terminal, I get the following error:

```
unix.stackexchange.com: command not found
```

This is ok and as I expected. But when I insert `http://unix.stackexchange.com`, I get another error message:

```
bash: http://unix.stackexchange.com: No such file or directory
```

I do not ask about why I get errors. I want to know why these are different and, eventually, which process/function handles them?

Comment: They are different because the latter contains forward slashes (`/`), which causes you shell to interpret it as a file path. Keep in mind that `/` is the directory separator in Unix-like OS:s, and cannot be present in a _filename_.

Comment: @ThomasNyman Ok, but do you know which processes/functions handles these errors?

Comment: @RaduRadeanu The errors originate from your shell, `bash` in this case. See my answer below for more details on the code paths which lead to the respective errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As also [ewhac pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97516/43779), the error messages differ because the latter command line contains forward slashes (`/`), which causes your shell to interpret it as a file path.

Both errors originate from your shell, which in this case is `bash` (which is evident from the second error message).

More specifically, the first error originates from the `execute_disk_command()` function defined in `execute_command.c` in the [`bash-4.2`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) source code. The `execute_disk_command()` function calls `search_for_command()` defined in `findcmd.c`, which, in case the specified `pathname` does not contain forward slashes, searches `$PATH` for the `pathname`. In case `pathname` contains forward slashes, `search_for_command()` does not perform this lookup. In case `search_for_command()` does not return a command, `execute_disk_command()` will fail with the `command not found` internal error.

The second error originates from the `shell_execve()` function, also defined in `execute_command.c`. At this point in your scenario,`search_for_command()` would have returned successfully because there would not have been any lookup needed, and `execute_disk_command()` has called `shell_execve()`, which in turn performs the `execve()` system call. This fails, because the file `execve()` attempts to execute does not exist, and `execve()` indicates this by setting `errno` appropriately. When `execve()` fails, `shell_execve()` uses `strerror()` to report the corresponding file error message (`No such file or directory`) and exits the shell immediately on the error.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I wanted to know. Now I think that I can edit bash source code and make an URL to be opened from terminal only by typing its name.

Answer (score 2):

The `/` character is a pathname separator.  The shell therefore assumes you're specifying a relative path to a command named `unix.stackexchange.com` under a directory named `http:`.  The shell fails to find the directory or the file, and says so.  You would get the same error message if you attempted to run a command named (for example): `foo/bar/grill/snorklewacker`.

On the other hand, if you enter a bare command name with no pathname separator, then the shell checks the list of directories in the `PATH` environment variable, in the order in which they appear, to see if they contain the program.  Thus, if you were to enter `unix.stackexchange.com` at a prompt on my system, the shell would conduct a search looking for:

- /usr/local/bin/unix.stackexchange.com
- /usr/bin/unix.stackexchange.com
- /bin/unix.stackexchange.com
- /usr/local/games/unix.stackexchange.com
- /usr/games/unix.stackexchange.com

If all of those searches fail, then you get the error `command not found`.